# Recuperar llave publicación Aplicación Android

Tags: android

Estimados muy buenos días, en mi organización se desea realizar una actualización de la actual app que se encuentra en el play de google, para eso tengo entendido que se requiere la llave con formato jks, lamentablemente esa llave no se encuentra y fue extraviada, puedo realizar el proceso de publicación de la app pero no funciona como actualización propiamente tal.

**¿Existirá la posibilidad de recuperar esa llave u alguna otra forma de generar el apk con esa key para el proceso de actualización?**

Comment: La llave es el .keystore y se recomienda no perderla!!! =0 !

Comment: Cuando vuelvas a crear otra, crea una de respaldo hasta debajo de las piedras(experiencia propia xD)

Comment: jajaj muchas gracias, esta quedará muy bien guardada.

Comment: existen tecnicas por ejemplo en la cual si recuerdas letras o palabras de tu llave puedes romperla por fuerza bruta XD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imposible si no se tiene el `keystore` que se firmo el `apk` inicialmente, lo que aconsejo es desactivar la actual app y subir la actualización, cómo si fuese una app nueva, ésto conlleva cambiar el identificador interno de la aplicación.

Para informar que hay una nueva actualización:
Puedes modificar la información de la ficha y despues poner la aplicación en modo "desactivada".
Los usuarios actuales que tengan la aplicación instalada, siempre verán la ficha de esa.
Los nuevos usuarios solo verán la ficha de la app nueva.

Guardar el `keystore` en un lugar seguro, y recomendable tener varias copias en la nube, usb disk, laptop etc...

Comment: Muchas gracias, esto quiere decir que si desactivo la app que está en producción tengo que dar aviso a todos los usuarios de mi app que existirá una actualización y que la actual app deben de dejar de utilizarla?, cómo me recomendarías hacerlo?

Comment: @Rodrigo Si, lo que puedes hacer es en la ficha de la app existente informar que hay nueva versión, que se instalen la nueva,  cuando desactivas una aplicación no se elimina, los usuarios que tienen la app instalada pueden ver la ficha en google play, los nuevos solo verán la nueva, el nombre lo puedes solapar vieja "mi app foo bar" nueva "mi app foo bar"

Comment: diculpa pero puedes orientarme donde se encuentra la ficha que me mencionas? o si más bien es posible enviarle un mensaje personalizado a los usuarios activos de mi app que en una fecha determinada la aplicación caducará y deben descargar una nueva?

Comment: @Rodrigo dentro del panel de "Google play Console" seleccionas la app, sección Ficha play store, actualiza la info, se debe esperar un tiempo para que se actualice la info.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, y con respecto a la otra pregunta es posible enviar algún mensaje a los usuarios activos de la app?, puedes orientarme con respecto a los "experimentos" que figuran en play console o más bien si me sirve esa opción para alertar a los usuarios.

Comment: @Rodrigo directamente al usuario no puedes informarlo, sobre el apartado "experimentos" ni idea de que sirve, puedes crear una nueva pregunta, así será visible para todos.

Comment: Muchas Gracias, así lo haré.

Answer (score 7):

Siempre realiza un respaldo en un lugar seguro y no olvides el usuario y passwords.

La llave que comentas tiene extensión **[.keystore](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)**

Si tuvieras el keystore, pero no los password probablemente podrías hacer algo con:

**http://code.google.com/p/android-keystore-password-recover/**

#### Si no se tiene el Keystore, definitivamente tienes que crear otro y subir una nueva aplicación a tu Play Store, ya que no podrías reemplazar la existente !

---

#### **[COMO FIRMAR TU APLICACIÓN !](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html?hl=es-419)**

Primeramente necesitas obtener un Keystore de producción para firmar la aplicación, eso se realiza mediante la utilería `keytool`, este es un ejemplo:

```
keytool -list -keystore your_keystore_name

keytool -list -v -keystore your_keystore_name -alias your_alias_name
```

Pero además de la utilería  `keytool` ahora para mayor facilidad puedes usar este método:

[**Firmar tu compilación de versión**](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html?hl=es-419#release-mode) (Si deseas crear un keystore nuevo, haz clic en Create new.)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con el archivo .keystore que obtengas debes firmar tu aplicación, desde el menú de Android Studio puedes realizarlo, te requerira la ruta de tu keystore:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

### ¿Cual diferencia entre `debug.keystore` y la keystore que yo genero para subir aplicaciones a Google Playstore?

El archivo `debug.keystore` regularmente se ubica en alguna de las siguientes rutas:

- `~/.android/` en SO X y Linux;
- `C:\Documents and Settings\<user>\.android\` en Windows XP;
- `C:\Users\<user>\.android\` en Windows Vista y Windows 7, 8 y 10.

**[pero este keystore NO es adecuado para firmar aplicaciones destinadas a la Google Playstore.](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#sign-auto), este es un Keystore o certificado para depuración.** Este certificado tiene una vigencia de un año, incluso puedes eliminarlo y al iniciar `Android Studio` generará otro nuevo.

> **Fecha de vencimiento del certificado de depuración** El certificado
>   autofirmado usado que se usa para firmar tu APK en el modo de
>   depuración tiene un plazo de vencimiento de 365 días a partir de su
>   fecha de creación. Cuando el certificado caduque, recibirás un error
>   de compilación.

a diferencia del certificado o keystore que nosotros generamos, el cual necesita un Alias su password, además de un password propio del Keystore. Incluso un punto importante es que puedes definir una vigencia de este certificado en años.

**https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#release-mode**

**Este keystore que generaste, a diferencia del `debug.keystore` es sumamente importante guardarlo**, realizar respaldo y evitar perderlo! porque no podrás subir actualizaciones firmadas de tu aplicación en caso de perderlo. Si lo pierdes te verás forzado a crear una nueva firma y subir otra aplicación diferente.

Incluso puedes configurar para que automáticamente se firme tu aplicación con este keystore que creaste para producción.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3):

Me pasó que tuve corrupto la keystore y pude igualmente actualizar generando una nueva y no tuve que resetear nada.

Solo se manda un email a Google explicando la situación y te piden un archivo .pem que se logra con una nueva keystore. Ellos te responden alrededor de 2 días máximo en mi caso y podes luego actualizar como siempre.

Comment: A que correo de Google escribiste?