# Error de certificado Google Play android

Tags: android, android-studio

Buenas tardes, Hace poco subí una app a google play, actualmente quiero subir una actualización pero no me deja, me aparece el siguiente error en la consola:

Error de subida

> Has subido un APK firmado con un certificado diferente al de los
>   archivos APK anteriores. Debes usar el mismo certificado. Tus APK
>   están firmados con un certificado digital que incluye la huella
>   digital [ SHA1: "un numero" ]

, mientras que el certificado que has utilizado para firmar el APK que has subido tiene la huella digital

> [ SHA1: "un numero diferente al de arriba" ]

Hace poco mi mac se trabó y tuve que formatearla y volver a instalar android studio, pero guardé mis proyectos.

Agradezco su apoyo!

Comment: Formateaste tu PC ....  ¿tienes el Keystore con el que subiste a Play Store la aplicación?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplemente debes firmar tu aplicación con el Keystore con el cual firmaste tu primera versión de la aplicación.

**Si firmas tu .apk con otro Keystore diferente, al tratar subirla como actualización, no se podrá realizar y se mostraria el mensaje:**

> Has subido un APK firmado con un certificado diferente al de los
> archivos APK anteriores. Debes usar el mismo certificado. Tus APK
> están firmados con un certificado digital que incluye la huella
> digital [ SHA1: "un numero" ]

**Si no cuentas con el Keystore con el cual subiste la primera versión de la aplicación, lo siento pero tendrías que subir una aplicación diferente.**

[Recuperar llave publicación Aplicación Android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/8508/recuperar-llave-publicaci%C3%B3n-aplicaci%C3%B3n-android/8509#8509)

---

Actualizaciòn:

**Si perdiste tu certificado, afortunadamente en la actualidad puedes comunicarte con el equipo de soporte de Google para requerir tu certificado.**

> **Claves de carga perdidas o comprometidas**
> Si perdiste la clave de carga
> privada o esta se ve comprometida, puedes [crear una nueva](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423#create) y pedirle al
> propietario de la cuenta que [**se comunique con el equipo de asistencia
> para que la restablezca**](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/otherbugs). Cuando lo haga, asegúrate de que adjunte el
> archivo upload_certificate.pem.

Revisa la documentaciòn oficial:

[Cómo usar la firma de apps de Google Play](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=es-419)

Comment: Desconozco donde se ubica el keystore, pero tengo respaldo de la aplicación, donde lo puedo ubicar?

Comment: ¿El keystore de producción con el cual subiste tu aplicación no sabes donde se encuentra? eso es un gran problema no podrás subir actualización de tu aplicación.

Comment: De hecho creo si fue más fácil subir una app diferente

Comment: @SergioGarcía la Keystore guardala en un lugar seguro y realiza respaldos de la misma para que no la vuelvas a perder =(.

Answer (score 1):

Si hiciste copia tienes que tener el keystore.
Mira en el directorio raíz, a lo mejor hay un archivo cuyo nombre puedas identificarlo como el almacén de claves que andas buscando. Las palabras **keystore** o **jks** pueden estar en algún nombre de fichero.

Yo en tu lugar buscaría bien antes de tirar lo toalla y dejar de actualizar tu App.