# Problema al instalar apk en ciertos equipos

Tags: ionic, ionic3, ionic-framework

Estoy trabajando con Ionic 3 cuando he creado el apk he tenido el siguiente problema que solo se a podido instalar en android 8 y 7.1 en las versiones inferiores como 7.0 hacia abajo no se ha podido instalar me sale el siguiente error.
[image: Error]

Lo que intente para solucionarlo sin éxito fue lo siguiente instale android 4.1.2 que viene hacer el SDK 16 el cual especifique en el archivo config.xml

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="16" />
<preference name="android-maxSdkVersion" value="16" />
```

He compilado(buil) `ionic cordova build android` he creado la apk supuestamente para que se pueda instalar desde Android 4.1.2 hacia arriba pero no instala en equipos que tienen Android 7.0 solo instala desde 7.1 hacia arriba.

Corriendo este comando `ionic cordova platform ls` me sale lo siguiente.

[image: plataform ls]

Con la configuración que hice en el config.xml pensé que podría ser la solución pero no fue así, ¿Que puedo hacer para solucionarlo?

Saludos!

Comment: Hey Pieter, el mismo .ask que generaste  falla al instalarse en dispositivos 7.0 o mejor? Debes asegurar fue creado  el apk con el mismo certificado y verifica  no este instalado ve a aplicaciones en configuracion  y revisa, probablemente  se instalo con una cuenta "guest"

Comment: Como puedo revisar si no se instala @Jorgesys

Comment: @Jorgesys Te cuento que instale android 6.1.1 compile y me sigue dando el mismo problema, lo que he leído es que eso se soluciona en subir el apk al play store, ¿no se si habrá otra solución?

Comment: Me parece que tal vez firmaste el apk con un certificado diferente, asegura firmar el .apk con el mismo certificado con el cual se sube a la PlayStore. Revisa esta pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/109116/error-de-certificado-google-play-android @PedroAvila

Comment: @Jorgesys Todavía no lo he subido a playstore debería cambiarle la versión ´<widget id="TecSoftware.Ubikate.ionic" version="0.0.1"´

Comment: El importante es el versionCode y el paquete debe ser el mismo (TecSoftware.Ubikate.ionic), si es diferente puede mostrar el problema que comentas.

Comment: Como te comente aún no he subido nada solo lo estoy probando en diferentes dispositivos y me muestra el error comentado en mi pregunta.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80567/discussion-between-jorgesys-and-pedro-avila).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema que tenía se soluciono cambiando el nombre del id que estaba con letra capital al parecer todo debe estar en minúscula.

```
widget id="io.ionic.starter"
```

Eso fue todo el problema, también tuve que cambiar de versión de android para poder instalar desde 6.1.1 hacia adelante.