# Problemas con KeyStore Google Play en Xamarin

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, google-play, keystore

Buenas tardes colegas,

Es para solicitar ayuda sobre el fallo que tengo al momento de subir mi aplicación Android realizada en Xamarin, pero siempre me arroja problemas con la KeyStore.

1. Existe alguna forma de restablecer la KeyStore.
2. Puedo descargar la KeyStore desde la consola de Google Play.
3. Puedo crear una nueva KeyStore y asociarla en la consola de Google Play.

A continuación, adjunto captura de pantalla del error que tengo. gracias por la ayuda.

[image: o]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Existe alguna forma de restablecer la KeyStore.

**No, es muy importante que al crear tu Keystore lo respaldes y almacenes en un lugar seguro**, ya que si firmas tu aplicación y la subes a Google Play, las siguientes versiones (actualizaciones) deben ser firmadas con el mismo certificado.

> Puedo descargar la KeyStore desde la consola de Google Play.

[Puedes crear una nueva Keystore](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing), pero no podrás firmar una actualización.

https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#generate-key

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Puedo crear una nueva KeyStore y asociarla en la consola de Google
>   Play.

Puedes crear una nueva pero la aplicación que subas será considerada como nueva ya que para subir actualizaciones necesitas el Keystore con el que fue firmada la primera versión que se encuentra en Google Play.

---

**Si perdiste la Keystore con la cual firmaste la versión actual que se encuentra en Google Play**, **no podrás subir una actualización de la actual.** Únicamente podrás subir una aplicación que será considerada nueva para Google Play.

[Error de certificado Google Play android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/109116/error-de-certificado-google-play-android)

[Recuperar llave publicación Aplicación Android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/8508/recuperar-llave-publicaci%C3%B3n-aplicaci%C3%B3n-android/8509#8509)