# Error en la carga Android App Bundle está firmado con una clave no válida?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

Hace poco subí una app a google play, actualmente quiero subir una actualización pero no me deja, me aparece el siguiente error en la consola:

> Error en la carga Tu Android App Bundle está firmado con una clave no
>   válida. Asegúrate de que contenga la clave de firma correcta y vuelve
>   a intentarlo: SHA1:
>   90:3B:B8:1D:30:FA:28:95:06:F3:44:14:61:62:EB:E3:C0:5D:FE:0B.

tengo todo:

```
la contraseña, 
el keystore, 
el alias,
```

Simplemente me sale el mismo Error y no lo logro solucionar, Agradezco de antemano si tiene alguna ayuda sobre este tema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo que realizaste un comentario en la pregunta:

[Error de certificado Google Play android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/109116/error-de-certificado-google-play-android)

El keystore con el que ahora firmaste tu .apk de actualización no tiene el mismo certificado que debería ser:

```
SHA1: 90:3B:B8:1D:30:FA:28:95:06:F3:44:14:61:62:EB:E3:C0:5D:FE:0B
```

Tienes la contraseña, el keystore, el alias pero definitivamente esto se debe a que estas usando un Keystore diferente con el que firmaste la primera versión de la aplicación.

Por esa razón **es sumamente importante al generar nuestro Keystore guardarlo, realizar respaldo y evitar perderlo! porque de otra forma no podrás subir actualizaciones firmadas de tu aplicación en caso de perderlo. Si lo pierdes te verás forzado a crear una nueva firma y tendrás que subir una aplicación diferente (diferente package name).**

[Recuperar llave publicación Aplicación Android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/8512/95)

Comment: te agradezco, pero no puede ser esa la respuesta, yo a penas lo cree lo guarde y copie el password, estoy cien por ciento seguro de que ese es mi keystore, te agradezco por tu tiempo, pero ya pedi cambio de clave al soporte de google play, mil gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: **Cada Keystore, se crea con un SHA1 único**,  si cambia la única razón puede ser porque este Keystore fue sobreescrito :-(.