# Como hago para utilizar el "Certificado de la clave de firma de la app" de google play console

Tags: android-studio, google-play-console, keystore

Resulta que me genera en la seccion de "Certificado de la clave de firma de la app" genera unas claves para la firma de mi apk, pero descargo el certificado y sale en un archivo que no es copatible con la key.jks y nose que mas hacer, es la primera vez que intento publicar una app a play store y no se como hacer esto, si alguien conociera o ya paso por este problema por favor ayudarme...

adjunto la otra imagen que aparece, y el mensaje que me dice es

Error en la carga Tu Android App Bundle está firmado con una clave no
válida. Asegúrate de que contenga la clave de firma correcta y vuelve
a intentarlo: SHA1:
90:3B:B8:1D:30:FA:28:95:06:F3:44:14:61:62

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, ¿Ya revisaste la documentación? https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing?hl=es

Comment: Es que la app con la que subiste la primera versión fue firmada con un certficado distinto, debes asegurar guardar el certificado y usar siempre el mismo para poder realizar actualizaciones de tu aplicación. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/308231/error-en-la-carga-android-app-bundle-est%c3%a1-firmado-con-una-clave-no-v%c3%a1lida