# ¿Se puede cambiar la firma de un APK? y subir a la play store

Tags: android, apk

Tengo un negocio (Local de comidas rápidas) en el cual tengo una APP para android donde los clientes pueden hacer sus pedidos por ese medio. esta app yo se la adquiri por abono mensual a un tercero. este acuerdo llego a su fin ya que a la persona que le adquiri esta app no quiso seguir vendiendome el servicio porque segun el la app tenia muchos errores. cuestion es que me quiso vender una webapp que no me gusto para nada y le pedi por favor que yo queria seguir trabajando con la app nativa. la persona no quiso (seguramente habra tenido algun problema con el que le vendio la apk, sinceramente no lo se) yo se que el es un reveendedor y el no creo la app pero no me quiere decir a quien se la compro ni nada. cuestion es que la dio de baja de google play y ahora mis clientes no pueden bajar la aplicacion. (el archivo APK funciona a la perfeccion. yo sigo recibiendo los pedidos y todo) la unica diferencia es que no esta disponible en google play lo que dificulta enormemente que un cliente comun y corriente acceda a a la app.

el tema es el siguiente yo no conozco practicamente nada de programacion y cuando quise subir el archivo apk a google play claro me salto el error de que la firma no es mia. cuestion es que intente "desglozar" el archivo apk intentar cambiar la firma etc pero sinceramente de programacion no entiendo casi nada.
entonces mi pregunta es la siguiente. esto se puede hacer?

**¿hay alguna forma de cambiar la firma para asi poder subir la apk a google play?** hay alguna manera? gracias espero sus respuestas es muy importante para mi ya que sin la app pierdo practicamente mi negocio de comidas

Comment: Hola Fabian mira a ver si lo que dicen en esta respuesta te es util [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3267401/7867889) . Un consejo , aunque el transfondo de tu pregunta es importante te recomiendo(para que no te la cierren por demasiado amplia) [edit] tu pregunta poniendo solo el problema es decir que intentas cambiar la firma y lo que has intentado. Un saludo

Answer (score 2):

Cuando subes una actualización de tu aplicación a la Play Store, esta debe ser firmada con el mismo Keystore con el cual subiste su primera versión.

Por esta razón **es muy importante que al crear tu Keystore lo respaldes y almacenes en un lugar seguro, ya que si firmas tu aplicación y la subes a Google Play, las siguientes versiones (actualizaciones) deben ser firmadas con el mismo certificado.**

Si no te pueden proporcionar el Keystore con el cual se subió la primera versión, desafortunadamente no podrás subir una actualización de la aplicación, la única opción que tienes es subir una "nueva" aplicación, que en realidad sería la misma pero debe tener diferente "package name"  que es también tu `applicationId` ya que Play Store no permite el mismo id

```
android {
    ...
    ... 
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.gruporeforma.noticiasplay"
    ...
    ...
    }

}
```

Esta "nueva" versión debe ser firmada con otro Keystore el cual tu puedes crear.

Puedes revisar estas preguntas relacionadas:

[Error de certificado Google Play android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/109116/error-de-certificado-google-play-android)

[Recuperar llave publicación Aplicación Android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/8508/recuperar-llave-publicaci%C3%B3n-aplicaci%C3%B3n-android/8509#8509)